# Does Web ADF 10 work with ASP.net 4?

Tags: arcgis-server, asp.net, arcgis-web-adf

I already have an ASP.net application using VS 2010 and .NET framework version 4 and ArcGIS Server 10, and I need to add just a page, have map and toolbar.

When I try to add map control and run the page the map is not displayed. I just want to add page to that application having map and toolbar controls.

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Web ADF for .Net runs on 3.5 framework and the latest VS2010 is on 4.0 framework. When you open the website it asks for the conversion of framework. Click on no and then project gets uploaded and once executed the map will be showen.